# Create a dynamic description content when sharing a link on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to make a dynamic description/title text when sharing a link at Facebook?
I'm using Facebook's API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query string to generate a dynamic description and title so that when facebook tries to call your URL using the query string they find another description so you have to write a code in the page load to update title and description meta tags depending on the query string.